# Extracting values from correlation response in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

In Loadrunner i have retrieved values using correlation.

the function looks like this for the correLation:

```
web_reg_save_param("flight_number",
        "LB=outboundFlight value=",
        "RB=>",
        "ORD=ALL",
        "SaveOffset=-15",
        LAST);

**And the response i recieve is like this:**
Action.c(88): Notify: Saving Parameter "flight_number_1 = 030;251;03/01/2014 checked ".
Action.c(88): Notify: Saving Parameter "flight_number_2 = 031;224;03/01/2014".
Action.c(88): Notify: Saving Parameter "flight_number_3 = 032;238;03/01/2014".
Action.c(88): Notify: Saving Parameter "flight_number_4 = 033;206;03/01/2014".
```

If i want to extract only the first three values that is 030 or 031 and the like then how do i do it?

Comment: Savelenght usage is not possible since the entire value 030;251;03/01/2014 is dynamic

Comment: Could you please add the source HTML from which the values are taken? It seems that you can simply use ; as the RB parameter of the web_reg_save_param call

Comment: Another solution (without knowing the original server response) would be to split the parameter value. You can do this with JavaScript like this: web_js_run("Code=LR.getParam('flight_number').split(';')[0]","ResultParam=flight_number_parsed",LAST); (note that you must enable JavaScript to use this step). Or you can do it in C code.

Comment: the html response looks like this:

Comment: name=outboundFlight value=030;250;03/01/2014 checked >Blue Sky Air 030<td align=center>8am<td align=center>$ 251</TD></TR><
tr bgcolor=#EFF2F7><td align=center><input type = radio name=outboundFlight value=031;224;
     03/01/2014>Blue Sky Air 031<td align=center>1pm<td align=center>$ 224</TD></TR><tr bgcolor
    =#EFF2F7><td align=center><input type = radio name=outboundFlight value=032;238;03/01/2014
    >Blue Sky Air 032<td align=center>5pm<td align=center>$ 238</TD></TR><tr bgcolor=#EFF2F7><
    td align=center><input type = radio name=outboundFlight value=033;206;03/01/2014>Blue Sky

Answer (score 1):

Change the RB to ;

My answer needs to be longer so I am writing this line.

Answer (score 0):

Use C String processing to pull a substring of the first three characters into a new string.  see strncpy()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are beginer

at this moment use the web reg save param with ord =1,2 and 3 with different save param name

or

you can access them using the array param_1, Param_2 as you are using it as ORD=ALL